# Grunt fails to complete tasks, although it gives no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have quite a few tasks in my `Gruntfile.js`, and they are configured properly. When run individually, they all complete perfectly and create the desired output. However, when I list them under one task, for example as `default` (or anything else), they seem to complete without errors, but `style.css` does not exist. I believe it gets created and then somehow it's being erased? Although I can't figure out why, because when I run all those tasks in the same order but individually, everything's fine.

So, this does not generate `style.css` (although there are no errors!):

```
grunt.registerTask( 'default',  [

    'tidy',
    'svg2png',
    'sprites',
    'icons',
    'fonts',
    'copy:htc',
    'less:dev',
    'concat',
    'watch'

] );
```

But when I split those tasks in two, they work alright:

```
grunt.registerTask( 'generate', [

    'tidy',
    'svg2png',
    'sprites',
    'icons',
    'fonts',
    'copy:htc',

] );

grunt.registerTask( 'compile-dev',  [

    'less:dev',
    'concat',
    'watch'

] );
```

Why is this happening?

Here's a list of the plugins I'm using:

```
// Load modules

grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-less' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-concat' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-uglify' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-watch' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-clean' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-imagemin' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-copy' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-cleanempty' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-webfont' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-ttf2woff' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-ttf2eot' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-svg2png' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-fontface' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-spritesmith' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-newer' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-notify' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-processhtml' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-htmlclean' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-prettify' );
```

Comment: Have you tried running with `--verbose` and `--stack` options?

Comment: I just tried it, and it only adds confusion. The task which does not fully complete is `less:dev`. Here's a dump of what happens: http://pastedown.ctrl-c.us/#srmR42K9nHL9ifDu0hXtP-KT454.markdown

Comment: I suggest you remove tasks, one by one, from the list of tasks that fail. Figure out which removal stops the problem. Then start there, maybe adding to this question.